# Boost shared_ptr example program

Tags: c++, boost, foreach, shared-ptr

I was trying to get familiar with boost shared ptr. I came across the following example.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

/*  The application will produce a series of
*  objects of type Foo which later must be
*  accessed both by occurrence (std::vector)
*  and by ordering relationship (std::set).
*/

struct Foo
{
    int x;

    Foo( int y ) : x(y)
    {

    }
    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructing a Foo with x=" << x << "\n";
    }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

struct FooPtrOps
{
    bool operator()( const FooPtr & a, const FooPtr & b )
    {
        return true; //a->x > b->x;
    }
    void operator()( const FooPtr & a )
    {
        std::cout << a->x << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<FooPtr>         foo_vector;
    std::set<FooPtr,FooPtrOps>  foo_set; // NOT multiset!

    FooPtr foo_ptr( new Foo( 2 ) );
    foo_vector.push_back( foo_ptr );
    foo_set.insert( foo_ptr );

    foo_ptr.reset( new Foo( 1 ) );
    foo_vector.push_back( foo_ptr );
    foo_set.insert( foo_ptr );

    foo_ptr.reset( new Foo( 3 ) );
    foo_vector.push_back( foo_ptr );
    foo_set.insert( foo_ptr );

    foo_ptr.reset ( new Foo( 2 ) );
    foo_vector.push_back( foo_ptr );
    foo_set.insert( foo_ptr );

    std::cout << "foo_vector:\n";
    std::for_each( foo_vector.begin(), foo_vector.end(), FooPtrOps() );

    std::cout << "\nfoo_set:\n";
    std::for_each( foo_set.begin(), foo_set.end(), FooPtrOps() );
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

My question is the `for_each()` loop and how does it demonstrate the functionality of a `shared_ptr`? The third paramerter that they are passing to the `for_each()` loop is `FooPtrOps()` (which I am assuming is the overloaded operator () in class FooPtrOps()). But the signature doesn't seem to match with the definitions provided in the class.And still not clear how this demonstrates the functionalities of `boost_shared_ptr`

The output that I am getting for the above program is

```
foo_vector:
2
1
3
2

foo_set:
2
3
1
2

Destructing a Foo with x=2
Destructing a Foo with x=1
Destructing a Foo with x=3
Destructing a Foo with x=2
```

Comment: I think it's just trying to show you that `4` objects were instantiated, `2` different containers each hold all `4` objects (i.e., the same `4` objects), and finally only `4` objects are destroyed.

Comment: Also note that `FooPtrOps()` is a default constructed FooPtrOps object. That's what's being passed into the `foreach` function.  Inside `foreach` it calls the operator()(const FooPtr & a) member function.

Comment: @AnonMail - for_each loop documentation indicates that the third parameter should be a lambda function (not an object? )

Comment: @liv2hak The [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) documentation states it's a templated type that meets the requirements of a unary function (i.e., a function object, a function, and a lambda all can work).

Comment: @liv2hak See this [Live Example](http://ideone.com/gFMeeK).

Comment: @JamesAdkison - thanks. much appreciated.